# Build project in VS2015: "csc.exe" exited with code -1073741571

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, stack-overflow, csc

I was using Visual studio 2013. Yesterday, I installed VS2015(enterprise update 3). The build process for my solution crashes in VS2015 for one of the projects. The same exception occurs with VS2017 RC.
The solution was building succesfully in VS2013.

The solution is targeting .Net4.5. When I migrate to .Net4.6.2, it does not solve this issue.

I believe the problem is coming with compiler included in VS2015+

Output :

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -1073741571.

Msbuild command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe \
  /noconfig \
  /nowarn:1591,1701,1702,2008 \
  /nostdlib+ \
  /errorreport:prompt \
  /warn:4 \
  /define:TRACE;DEBUG;DOMAIN_IMPL \
  /errorendlocation \
  /preferreduilang:en-US \
  /highentropyva+ \
  /reference:[...] \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Configuration.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Core.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Data.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll"  \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Xml.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Collections.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Globalization.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.IO.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Linq.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Threading.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" \
  /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" \
  /debug- \
  /filealign:512 \
  /optimize- \
  /out:obj\Debug\EA4T.SteadyBear.Domain.dll \
  /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\AllRules.ruleset" \
  /subsystemversion:6.00 \
  /resource:[...] \
  /target:library \
  /utf8output [...].cs "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
```

When debugging csc using windbg, here is what occurs: http://pastebin.com/d8AiaSgh
. Everything falls down into many `Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_ni` frames. Please note that code analysis is disabled in the project settings.

Comment: please run msbuild as administrator and build again, check if it works. if the issue still exists, please share a simple demo, which could reproduce the issue. in addition, here is a similar issue for your reference. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1882825/c-project-crashed-with-csc-exe-exited-with-code-2146232797-0-while-compiling-valid-code-with-async-templace

Comment: Running as admin in a command line does not solve, but it changes the exit code : -2147023895.

I cannot build a simple demo because I have no clue about the failing code.  
About the issue you are pointing to, it does not match anything in my project.

Comment: Please create a new project and copy the files from the error project to new project, then add the files to project and check if it works  (please add related reference).

Comment: I created the Csproj file from scratch using VS2015 and added the source files into it. Same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue occurs when the project contains 1024+ fluent chained call.

In the following sample, if FluentMethod() is call more than 1024 times on foo, the compiler will crash.

```
var foo= new Foo();
var result = foo
.FluentMethod()
.FluentMethod()
...;
```

Efficient workaround is to split fluent call into smaller group :

```
var temp = foo.FluentMethod().FluentMethod();
var result = temp.FluentMethod().FluentMethod();
```

There is [an issue on the compiler github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9795) about this

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem was the memory usage of the system.

The `StandardCollector.Service.exe` took a Commit Size of 74GB, so it snooped all memory of the system and more. After killing it, memory freed up and the build in Jenkins completed without errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Code Contracts installed and enabled, go to the Code Contracts tab in the offending project's properties and uncheck "Emit contracts into XML doc file".

Comment: Code contracts is not installed in VS. It cannot impact building process...